# Is there new Update Panel components for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, atlas

There was a time, when ASP.NET AJAX was Atlas Alpha version. And there were some projects for update panels: Comfort ASP, FastPage (mine:)), MagicAjax, ZumiPage. Now looks like all they dead. What people now use for update panels, except Asp.Net Ajax that is loading huge amount of js not needed for update panel. I have problems with MagicAjax installing on .net4, its deleting my scripts I dont know why. So is there update panels that 100% is working on .net4 and know about jquery.

Used MagicAjax more old version - and now it works)

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly: do you want to use an implementation of `UpdatePanel` other than the one provided by `System.Web.Extensions`? Last time I checked, that assembly did not emit that many scripts on the page...

Comment: really not so many, around 35 kb of gzipped (240 not compressed) fully not needed code, as compare my update panel was 3 kb not compressed, magic ajax 19 kb not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question.

Here's whay I use:

- I am using the Ajax toolkit (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) and indeed regular update panels and that is working fine for me.
- Also I am more and more just using JQuery (http://jquery.com/). Very easy to integrate with asp.net.

Comment: I said "except Asp.Net Ajax", also except Telerik RadAjax and MagicAjax.

Comment: You said "Except asp.net Ajax updatepanels..." and last time I checked jquery is not Asp.net Ajax

Comment: Yes) I remembered some more "except") means wants something free

Comment: Really Jquery is not Asp.Net Ajax and is not an update panel)) so why you say about it?